# Eclipse canvas paintListener never called

Tags: java, eclipse, canvas, plugins, swt

I'm creating an editor extension to eclipse, and a for a part of the editor I need to draw simple graphical parts. From what I understand I should be able to use the eclipse widget Canvas for this. But the paintControl method of the PaintListener added to the canvas is never called. I'm assuming I'm missing some crucial simple part but I can't find it. Here is the code that creates, adds and calls redraw on the canvas.

```
void createGraphicPage() {
    Composite composite = new Composite(getContainer(), SWT.NONE);
    drawWidget = new Canvas(composite, SWT.NONE);

    FormLayout layout = new FormLayout();
    drawWidget.setLayout(layout);
    drawWidget.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            System.out.println("inDrawWidget");
            Rectangle r = drawWidget.getClientArea();
            e.gc.drawOval(0, 0, r.width, r.height);
        }
    });
    drawWidget.redraw();
    int index = addPage(composite);
    setPageText(index, "Graphics Editor");
}
```

Comment: Setting a layout on the `drawnWidget` is unnecessary, bu you haven't assigned a layout to its parent (the one named `composite`). What is the size of the `drawnWidget`?

Comment: I tried setting the same layout to composite with no difference in behaviour. WIth size I assume you mean r.width and height? I dont know what they are since the method is never called, i Cant debug or print them:S

If i call drawWidget.getClientArea() outside of the paintlistener I get width and height 0. Should they not inherit something from the parent composite? If I call getContainer.getClientArea() i get the size (0, -20)

Comment: The 'width and height 0' of the `drawnWidget` is why the PaintListener is never called. Children don't inherit layouts or sizes from their parents. Assign a suitable layout to its parent, see [Understanding Layouts in SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) for more on layouts in SWT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a layout on each `Composite` which contains controls, and usually set layout data on the controls. So:

```
Composite composite = new Composite(getContainer(), SWT.NONE);
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Canvas drawWidget = new Canvas(composite, SWT.NONE);
drawWidget.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

drawWidget.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
    @Override
    public void paintControl(final PaintEvent e) {
        System.out.println("inDrawWidget");
        final Rectangle r = drawWidget.getClientArea();
        e.gc.drawOval(0, 0, r.width, r.height);
    }
});
```

I have added a `GridLayout` to the `Composite` and `GridData` layout data to the `Canvas`. The `GridData` makes the `Canvas` use all available space.